# How Can I Debug Flutter Projects Using GitPod?

Tags: flutter, gitpod

I'm trying to debug my flutter project on in chrome browser using GitPod but I'm new to both. I found a repo on GitHub that achieves this: https://github.com/vtorres/gitpod-flutter

and I tried saving the raw .gitpod.yml and .gitpod.dockerfile and adding them to my project repo but I was not able to successfully run / debug in chrome: https://github.com/XavierRenegadeAngel/firestore-troubleshooting

any ideas what I'm missing here or how this can be done? thank you!

also, is there a way to emulate android with gitpod for flutter projects?

Comment: Did you check out this doc? https://www.gitpod.io/docs/quickstart/flutter

Comment: @AndreaFalzetti no i didnt know about this! god bless you

Comment: DId you find a solution? You can use appetize to run the app but it did not figure out how to get a logcat

Comment: How do I see the output of `print`? What is the address to see the logs?